# how to use commit to save all query and if any one query failed no data should be save

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, commit, autocommit

I have an employee form.In that i have used tabbed pane to get four different tabs.But problem is that if i save data on first tab only it get saved in database. and before saving data on other tabs i closed the overall form.so in database i have entry from first tab and no data saved for other tab...It gives me error for further process. I know about commit but i don't know where n how to use it???? i must want to save all data from all tabs of form to database and if in between form get closed no data should be get saved...Please help me.

I want it in java programming.and Each tab's data i save on its own page not at the last.

Answer (score 1):

You should set a rollback point before saving data from first tab, if on other tab somethings goes wrong, then you can rollback you last transaction to discard the changes and bring the database to its previous state.

Here is a sample code that is for MYSQL. Hope it will help.

```
Drop table Books;


CREATE TABLE Books
(
   ID SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   Copyright YEAR NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=INNODB;


select * from Books;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (103, 'Angels', 1966);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (104, 'Black', 1932);

SAVEPOINT sp1;

INSERT INTO Books VALUES (105, 'None', 1996);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (106, 'A', 1980);

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sp1;

INSERT INTO Books VALUES (107, 'Postcards', 1992);
INSERT INTO Books VALUES (108, 'The', 1993);

COMMIT;

select * from Books;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, you need to issue a BEGIN statement or alike to start a transaction, then run your queries, if they succeed, you run a COMMIT or alike, if they don't you will run a ROLLBACK to undo any query that occurred after BEGIN within your session.